# Javascript: Get next occurence of div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I make one universal function that will only affect the next ocurrence of div with the class="hiddenDiv" relative to the clicked link?

Like this:

```
<p><a href="#" class="showDivLink">click to show/hide div</a></p>
    <div class="hiddenDiv">
        <p>Text within hidden div.</p>
    </div>
```

I want to be able to write this so that I can insert a link with the class="showDivLink" before any div with class="hiddenDiv" that I wish to be able to show/hide. 
The link should only affect the first occurence of div relative to the link.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: What do you mean by turn on and off. do you want to hide the div or something on clicking?

Comment: you can use jquery methods parent and children; i mean something like this: $('.showDivLink').parent().children()[1]

Comment: @polin Yes I want to show and hide the next occurance of the <div class="hiddenDiv>.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) method. Add id attribute to `div` and handle `onClick` event.

```
<script type="javascript">
    function onAClicked() {
        var div = document.getElementById("hiddenDivId");
        //do whatever you want to div.
    }
</script>
....
<p><a href="#" class="showDivLink" onClick="onAClicked">click to show/hide div</a></p>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDivId">
    <p>Text within hidden div.</p>
</div>
```

**UPD:** if there can be a large number of links with div I suggest using `this` var. You should do something like the following

```
<script type="javascript">
    function onAClicked(id) {
        var div = document.getElementById("hiddenDivId" + id);
        //do whatever you want to div.
    }
</script>
....
<p><a href="#" class="showDivLink" id="1" onClick="onAClicked(this.id)">click to show/hide div</a></p>
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDivId1">
    <p>Text within hidden div.</p>
</div> 
<p><a href="#" class="showDivLink" id="N" onClick="onAClicked(this.id)">click to show/hide div</a></p>
....
<div class="hiddenDiv" id="hiddenDivIdN">
    <p>Text within hidden div.</p>
</div>
```

UPD2: and even more, you can use `window.event`

```
<script type="javascript">
    function onAClicked() {
        var e = window.event,
            obj = e.target || e.srcElement,
            id = e.id,
            div = document.getElementById("hiddenDivId" + id);
        //do whatever you want to div.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I know about that. But then if I have more divs and more links to show/hide these I will have to write a big ole bunch of functions, right. Or can I make one universal function that will only affect the next ocurrance of div relative to the clicked link?

Comment: @MagnusGaarde,got it. I think that should be specified in question

Comment: Will I not need to give each div a unique id with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.hiddenDiv').before(<your html code>)`. Try to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

This code was also published at http://scottizu.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/using-javascript-to-show-and-hide-div-elements/.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function myShow(node) {
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + "_SIB1_" + node.nextSibling.nodeName; // Text
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + "_SIB2_" + node.nextSibling.nextSibling.nodeName; // Div
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + "_SIB2_ID_" + node.nextSibling.nextSibling.id; // myDiv
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + "_SIB2_VISIBILITY_" + node.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.visibility;
    node.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function myHide(node) {
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + '_P_' + node.parentNode.nodeName; // Div      node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + '_P_ID_' + node.parentNode.id; // myDiv
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML + "_P_VISIBILITY_" + node.parentNode.style.visibility;
    node.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a title='myShowLink' onclick='myShow(this)'>Click to Show Div</a>
<div id='myDiv'>
    <a title='myHideLink' onclick='myHide(this)'>Click to Hide Div</a> 
    More Info
</div>
</body>
</html>
```